# Has or Has been

Tags: passive-voice

could you please tell me if there's something wrong with my example below or it is grammatical

> I can say that My English vocabulary has been improved a lot with the help of your English lesson videos

As you can see there's a clause [with the help of...] so I add [been] to make it in the passive voice and sounds better
And [has been in this example] will only work if there's a clause next to it(am I right?).

What's your thought?
You can also give a better example if you want

-Your comment will be appreciated thank you!.

Comment: Hello Beginner and welcome to ELL. Unfortunately, on this site, asking for proofreading is off-topic. If you have one aspect of your sentence that you're unsure about, please edit your question to ask just about that one aspect -- for instance, "with the help of", or the passive voice, or present perfect.

Comment: I don't agree that the passive voice sounds better. You can say that your vocabulary _has improved_ (it's better than it used to be), or that it _has been improved by_ watching the videos (they have made it better).

Comment: What @KateBunting said. In fact, I would say that the passive sounds *significantly **worse*** in this exact context - at least *partly* because of ***with the help of*** (which implies addressee's videos weren't the *only* factor causing improvement). The normal preposition would be ***by*** rather than ***with*** anyway, but to my ear the passive tends to imply a *single* "agent of change"; the construction doesn't work so well if it's implied that ***multiple factors*** led to the improvement, *of which **only one** is explicitly specified*.